FlutterError (Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe
I am trying to create a real time chat app with flutter. I don't understand why it is giving this error even if everything is correct.The error is coming on line 186.
i get the following error:
"Exception has occurred. FlutterError (Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe. At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable. To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.)"
enter image description here
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/chatpage.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/database_chatapp/database.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/database_chatapp/shared_orefer.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool search = false;
  final TextEditingController _searchController = new TextEditingController();
  var resultList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    _searchController.addListener(_onSearchChanged);
    ontheload();
    super.initState();
  }

  _onSearchChanged() {
    print(_searchController.text);
    showSearchResult();
  }

  List allResults = [];
  getClientStream() async {
    var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .orderBy("Name")
        .get();
    setState(() {
      allResults = data.docs;
    });
    showSearchResult();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _searchController.removeListener(_onSearchChanged);
    _searchController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    getClientStream();
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  showSearchResult() {
    var ShowResult = [];
    if (_searchController.text != "") {
      for (var clinetshot in allResults) {
        var name = clinetshot['Name'].toString().toLowerCase();

        if (name.contains(_searchController.text.toLowerCase())) {
          ShowResult.add(clinetshot);
        }
      }
    }
    setState(() {
      resultList = ShowResult;
    });
  }

  String? myname, myusername, mymail;

  getthesharepre() async {
    myname = await SharePreferenceHelper().getUserDisplayName();
    myusername = await SharePreferenceHelper().getUserMail();
    mymail = await SharePreferenceHelper().getUserMail();
    setState(() {});
  }

  ontheload() async {
    await getthesharepre();
    setState(() {});
  }

  getchatroomIdByUsername(String a, String b) {
    if (a.substring(0, 1).codeUnitAt(0) > b.substring(0, 1).codeUnitAt(0)) {
      return "$b>$a";
    } else {
      return "$a>$b";
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 66, 25, 90),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding:
                  EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 40, bottom: 20),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  search
                      ? Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                            controller: _searchController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              hintText: "Search Here",
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
                            ),
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        )
                      : Text(
                          "Chat APP",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        search = !search;
                        _searchController.clear();
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 4, 49),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                      child: search
                          ? Icon(
                              Icons.close,
                              color: Color.fromARGB(199, 230, 227, 227),
                            )
                          : Icon(
                              Icons.search,
                              color: Color.fromARGB(199, 230, 227, 227),
                            ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: search
                    ? EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 5)
                    : EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30, horizontal: 20),
                height: search
                    ? MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height / 1.16
                    : MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height / 1.15,
                width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(20))),
                child: search
                    ? ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: resultList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, Index) {
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () async {
                              search = false;
                              setState(() {});
                              var chatroomId = getchatroomIdByUsername(
                                  myusername!, resultList[Index]['UserName']);
                              Map<String, dynamic> chatroomInfoMap = {
                                "users": [
                                  myusername,
                                  resultList[Index]['UserName']
                                ],
                              };
                              await DataBaseMethod()
                                  .createChatRoom(chatroomId, chatroomInfoMap);
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => ChatPage(
                                          name: resultList[Index]["Name"],
                                          username: resultList[Index]["UserName"],
                                          mail: resultList[Index]["Email"])));
                            },
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: Text(resultList[Index]['Name']),
                              subtitle: Text(resultList[Index]['Email']),
                            ),
                          );
                        })
                    : Column(
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(70),
                                child: Image.asset(
                                  "images/rifathasan.jpg",
                                  height: 70,
                                  width: 70,
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 12,
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 7),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      "Sumi Akter",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 18,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 2,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "Hi,What are you doing?",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                          //fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                          color: Colors.black45),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Spacer(),
                              Text(
                                "04:18 PM",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    //fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                    color: Colors.black45),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 30,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(70),
                                child: Image.asset(
                                  "images/rifathasan.jpg",
                                  height: 70,
                                  width: 70,
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 12,
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 7),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      "Rifat Hasan Priyo",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 18,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 2,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "Do you know what....",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                          //fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                          color: Colors.black45),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Spacer(),
                              Text(
                                "07:23 PM",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    //fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                    color: Colors.black45),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


i trying do when click Profile then create a chatroom

Try this
ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: resultList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (_, Index) {
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () async {
                              search = false;
                              setState(() {});
                              var chatroomId = getchatroomIdByUsername(
                                  myusername!, resultList[Index]['UserName']);
                              Map<String, dynamic> chatroomInfoMap = {
                                "users": [
                                  myusername,
                                  resultList[Index]['UserName']
                                ],
                              };
                              await DataBaseMethod()
                                  .createChatRoom(chatroomId, chatroomInfoMap);
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => ChatPage(
                                          name: resultList[Index]["Name"],
                                          username: resultList[Index]["UserName"],
                                          mail: resultList[Index]["Email"])));
                            },
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: Text(resultList[Index]['Name']),
                              subtitle: Text(resultList[Index]['Email']),
                            ),
                          );
                        })

